# Can a capacitor of lower capacity than required be harmful?

Tags: capacitor, rectifier, maximum-ratings

I want to make a full wave rectifier for my highschool physics project. My mentor suggested I get a 24V 1000μF for it but I could only get my hands on a 50V 100μF capacitor. The voltage supply is a 9-0-9 transformer.

Can the low capacitance cause issues or will it just show weaker results?

[image]

Comment: That depends on where you use it. Can you show a cabling diagram?

Comment: 708 different ones to choose from, all in stock: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/aluminum-electrolytic-capacitors/58?s=N4IgjCBcoEwAwBYCcVQGMoDMCGAbAzgKYA0IA9lANrhy0AEArQGIgC6pADgC5QgCqAOwCWXAPKYAsoWz4ArgCdCIAL6l4AdhTQQGSF3myS5KiBgBWOgDUQpAMwXrpBHCs2QZl45AA2T2%2B%2B2rqTqfqQAHKE0fuwg3LyCIuJSMgpKqiAAtDCoOlD6hqQUkNRmbMrlQA. Otherwise, place ten 100 uF in parallel if you need 1000 uF.

Comment: What is your load? What are your project goals? With a smaller capacitor you will get more ripple with a given load. But for a learning experience, some ripple will be good.

Comment: What is the value of R? Do you have an oscilloscope? For a high-school project, if you only have a meter, plot the DC and AC voltage for various values of R. Do you understand ohms law and the power law? Know what power will be dissipated for various values. You don't want to burn yourself on a hot resistor.

Comment: @Mattman944 I dont have an oscilloscope. The school has a resistance box which can range from 1 ohm to about 30 kiloohms. And yes, i was planning on taking some readings to compare the AC vs DC voltage values as well. Thanks for the advice

Comment: If you are using a resistance box, then understand its ratings so you don't damage it with too much power.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a lot more ripple on the output under load. Whether that is a problem or not depends entirely on what the load is.

Comment: @PMF ive updated the post with a circuit diagram of what i plan to make.

Comment: thanks! its just going to be for a demonstration where I use an LED and a resistance box as needed

Comment: @MattMan944 thanks! Its just going to be for a demonstration where I use an LED and a resistance box as needed

Comment: then try it - you will learn something (if you use a scope to look at the output).

Comment: haha, is it going to fail so miserably? I dont mind a failure, but any suggestions on what to change?

Comment: it won't fail, but you should see an observable difference by changing the capacitor value when a load is connected.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice! I have 3 capacitors of 100 μF each so ill try the circuit out with 0, 1, 2, and 3 in parallel

Comment: Another thing you can observe without an oscilloscope is to move your head or the LED quickly and record what you see with no capacitor vs. capacitor(s).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't draw any current from the rectifier output (e.g. just measure the output voltage) then even 10μF would be enough.

But if you draw current it's going to be a different story.

- As you draw current (or decrease the load resistance) the output voltage will have more ripple because the output capacitor will discharge quicker (remember the RC time constant). The output DC voltage will reduce as you try to draw more current. After some point all you get will be [the rectified AC only](https://circuitglobe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/FULL-WAVE-BRIDGE-RECTIFIER-FIG-2-compressor.jpg). It's still DC but the value will be way less than expected (e.g. for the circuit in your question, the expected output is around ~8V but you'll get 4~5V). Also it's generally not useful because the voltage drops zero 100/120 times a second.
- As you try to draw more current (or decrease the load resistance) more RMS ripple current will flow through the smoothing capacitor. The maximum current is limited by the capacitor itself but if its ripple current rating is not high enough then this may result in explosion of the capacitor. We may not be able to make an assumption on the ripple current ratings just by looking at the capacitance and voltage values. But the thing is, don't use a single, low-value capacitor as a smoothing cap when there's a possibility of high current draw. To reduce the risk, use larger capacitors with potentially higher ripple current rating, or use multiple capacitors in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a potentially dangerous circuit, the line/mains voltage can kill you. The primary portion of the circuit should be in a metal box or well insulated with another method. If your teacher or someone else qualified can't help you with the left side, then you should pick another project.

Rohat has a good point regarding the ripple current rating of the capacitor. You can greatly reduce the risk by putting a 10 ohm resistor in series with the capacitor(s).

The maximum current allowed in a common LED is usually 20 mA. But, a modern LED is plenty bright at 1 mA. The LED presents another load to the circuit, so you need to make it negligible, or remove the LED for your measurements.

With a 200 ohm load, the power dissipated by the load resistor will be 9^2/20 or about 1/2 watt. Your resistor box can probably handle this, but you need to verify this.

Vary the load resistor from 200 ohms to 1000 ohms and see what happens.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftFXo2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]